# SSIS 2008R2 adding formula date column

Tags: ssis

I am importing a .CSV file into SQL server.  The data file has accounnt number, and dollar amount.  I would like to add a date field to the insert to SQL (the first of the last month), using this formula:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0), 101)
```

Where/How do I do this??  I attempted a Derived Column, but it didn't like the formula in the expression field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this expression to your derived column. Should get you what you want:

```
(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("day",-(DATEPART("day",DATEADD("Month",-1,GETDATE()))) + 1,DATEADD("Month",-1,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived column expression:

```
(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("MONTH",-1,((DT_DATE)((DT_STR,2,1252)MONTH(aDate) + "/01/" + (DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR(aDate))))
```

You would have to make sure that if you current date is a day in the month of January, the previous month would fall in the previous year. Example:

```
Current Date      First of previous month
02-15-2013        01-01-2013
12-15-2013        11-01-2013
01-15-2013        12-01-2012 (notice the year)
```